# Is it possible to combine AND and OR matches in a Virtual Service definition?

Tags: istio

I'm trying to define a Virtual Service in Istio (1.3.3) which has multiple matches but within the matches, there should be OR functionality.

For example : (pseudo code)

```
  match
     header-key = value1
  OR header-key = value2
  OR header-key = value3
  OR ....
  OR header-key = value100

AND 

  match
     uri-prefix = prefix1
  OR uri-prefix = prefix2
  OR uri-prefix = prefix3
  OR uri-prefix = ...
  OR uri-prefix = prefix100
```

So for every AND block there should be at least one matching OR condition.

I 've tried with a match but then if 1 of all the conditions are met, then it is valid, but what I want is to match one of the API keys and match one of the URI prefixes.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: test
  namespace: demo
spec:
  hosts:
  - test1
  gateways:
  - test-gateway  
  http:
    - match:
        - headers:
            apikey:
              exact: 111
        - headers:
            apikey:
              exact: 222
        - headers:
            apikey:
              exact: 333
        - uri:
            prefix: /path1/
        - uri:
            prefix: /path2/
      rewrite:
        uri: /newpath/v1/
        authority: test2
      route:
        - destination:
            host: test2
    - fault:
        abort:
          httpStatus: 444
          percent: 100
      route:
      - destination:
          host: test2
```

Comment: Check out this [github issue](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/14983)

Comment: @jt97, I simplified the problem to clarify, but in reality it will be more complex.The regex option (for headers -> apikey) doesn't seem to work for a lot of items in the regex condition.  How many items can I put in a regex condition ? I need more than 100 (perhaps even 500) apikeys which will be UUIDs.

And the second 'block' will be more complex (combination of uri and method), something like

`
  - match:
    - method:
        exact: GET
      uri:
        regex: "^/employees/[^/]+/assets/[^/]+$"
    - method:
        exact: POST
      uri:
        regex: "^/employees$"
`

Comment: As far as i'm concerned you should be able to make it for 100 or even 500 apikeys,the question is how big it's gonna be. I have found another idea to make it with [envoy.lua filter](https://github.com/istio/istio/issues/13819#issuecomment-498380290), maybe that's could be a better idea, let me know what You think.

Comment: @jt97, I tried regex match in virtual service with 500 items : 
00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000002|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000003|...|00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000500
and the configuration is accepted but when doing requests it only takes the first 10 to 12 keys in consideration and forwards request to destination. Trying with the other key values  routes the request to my fault section.
I'd rather avoid the envoy.lua if not really needed (also warning on istio documentation site to use envoy filters).

Comment: If regex didn't work as You expected I think envoy lua might be the answer, atleast worth to try it.